# Is there a way to hash a function itself?

Tags: python-3.x, function, hash

The problem that I want to solve is that I want a way to detect if the behavior of a function changes.

For example, let's say in python I write some functions `fun_a` and `fun_b`:

```py
def fun_a(a, b):
    return a + b


def fun_b(a, b, c):
    return a + fun_a(b, c)
```

And let's say I wanted to see if any behavior in `fun_a` has changed. I was thinking that what I could do is somehow come up with a hash function for functions, and then use the hashes to see if anything has changed, but that is of course easier said than done, and I find myself kind of torn over what is the best approach to take here.

One approach could be to just pickle `fun_a` and hash the resulting bytestring (or just use the bytestring as the "hash"), but this doesn't work if `fun_b` is modified (I've tested this out).

Another approach I thought of was to "probe" the inputs and outputs of the function by randomly sampling some inputs, running them through the function, and then getting the resulting outputs, and then hashing the input/output tuples. But the problem with that is that I don't think that generalizes very well to more complicated functions that have more complex inputs (ex: think of a function that generates the past tense of a provided English word and raises errors if you just give it gibberish). You would need to provide a hand-crafted set of inputs for those, which I think would be super flakey. Also, this sucks for functions that take a long time to run and you could also just get unlucky with the random sampling and provide inputs that don't change outputs for certain changes.

Maybe this entire problem was proved to be unsolvable, but if so, I was wondering if anyone could provide a reference on where to look for these kinds of problems. I can't have been the first person to wonder about this.

Comment: If the functions are not pure they can even behave differently without any change to the functions themselves. If however you limit this problem to pure functions, then you can use their source code as basis.

Comment: Adding to trincot, https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource gives you the source code as a string

Comment: Perhaps a different strategy would alleviate your need to even detect this, like a `__call__`-able class that stores `fun_a` as a private instance variable.

Comment: the behaviour of the function would change if the person (or script) changed the function. if the "critical" function was in its own file, you could **validate the timestamp of the file** and therefore know if "potential changes" have been made to the function....

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this won't fully cover your wishes. But if you want to get a string representation of your function including the function's body, you could use `inspect.getsource(your_function)`. Now you can hash this string representation of your function and see if it is still unchanged.

```
import inspect

def fun_a(a, b):
    return a + b

fun_a_hashed = hash(inspect.getsource(fun_a))
print(fun_a_hashed)
```

If you change anything in *fun_a*, such as in the following example, you would get a different hash as well.

```
def fun_a(a, b):
    return a - b

fun_a_hashed = hash(inspect.getsource(fun_a))
print(fun_a_hashed)
```

Now i do realise that any minor meaningless change in the text is now resulting in a different hash, even though the behavior might not have changed. So this needs a bit more tweaking to get it working properly.

Perhaps you could parse the string representation of the function and remove white-spaces, comments, etc.